# Discord.js not sending message in channel, but does send number in console

Tags: discord.js

I'm a very noob coder so I followed a tutorial to do most of this. I'm having an issue where a command used for my bot returns a number into the console instead of sending the message into the Discord channel. I noticed that "channel" in message.channel.send is a different color from the working blocks that did send messages. [Here's a screenshot of that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ax9UB.jpg)

Also, `client` and `args` are said to be undeclared despite already being declared at the start. It seems like the `module.exports` isn't using any variables I declared before the if statement, so that might be causing the problem? Thanks folks.

```
        module.exports={
            name: "quiz",
            description: "Test your knowledge about the Terrans.",
            category: "Trivia",
            run: async(client, message, args)=>{
                let q = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*(questions.length))];
                let i = 0;
                const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(q.title)
                .setDescription(q.options.map(opt=>{
                    i++;
                    return `${i} - ${opt}\n`
                }))
                embed.setFooter({text: "Reply with the number of the choice. You have 15 seconds."})
                message.channel.send({embeds:[Embed]})

                try{
                    let msgs = await message.channel.awaitMessages(u2=>u2.author.id===message.author.id, {time: 15000, max: 1, errors: ["time"]})
                    if(parseInt(msgs.first().content)==q.correct){
                        return message.channel.send(`Right on target.`)
                    }else{
                        return message.channel.send(`You\'re off the mark.`)
                    }
                }catch(e){
                    return message.channel.send(`Too slow!`)
                }        
            } 
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

On the lines 75, 77 and 80, you're sending the messages as a string. This would work in discord.js v12 but as you have to send objects now, you should be using `message.channel.send({content: 'Your message here'});`. Also don't understand why you are using the `module.exports` inside a command (check the screenshot to understand what I mean) as you only do that if you're using multiple files. You should only keep the code inside the `run: function(bot, message, args)` and remove everything from `module.exports` around it so you only have the following left:

```js
let q = questions[Math.floor(Math.random()*(questions.length))];
let i = 0;
const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(q.title)
.setDescription(q.options.map(opt=>{
    i++;
    return `${i} - ${opt}\n`
}))
embed.setFooter({text: "Reply with the number of the choice. You have 15 seconds."})

message.channel.send({embeds:[Embed]})

try{
    let msgs = await message.channel.awaitMessages(u2=>u2.author.id===message.author.id, {time: 15000, max: 1, errors: ["time"]})
    if(parseInt(msgs.first().content)==q.correct){
        return message.channel.send({content: `Right on target.`})
    }else{
        return message.channel.send(`You\'re off the mark.`)
    }
}catch(e){
    return message.channel.send({content: `Too slow!`})
}
```

Also I don't understand why you are using a map function inside the `setDescription` function as it returns an Array and you need to use a string.